# Bug with (dead) simple C program

Tags: c

Can somebody spot what's the problem with the following program, it doesn't print the numbers of the array like it supposed to

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{
    int d;
    for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
        printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not run it in a debugger?

Comment: Why the `+1` and `-1`? That's very strange.

Comment: What's the expected output, what's the *actual* output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast the condition:

```
d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)
```

[`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) returns the number of bytes in unsigned format.

[Before Cast](http://ideone.com/sjUUWm) and [After Cast](http://ideone.com/DxLCoX). Macros are not type-safe by themselves, without the cast both values get converted to unsigned values, and the result is false.

Comment: +1: The reason being that `-1` when converted to `unsigned` is way larger than `d`.

Comment: Also, I would change `TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))` to `TOTAL_ELEMENTS(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))` - it's cleaner.

Comment: `-Wsign-compare` (enabled by `-Wextra`).

Comment: `-Weverything` if you're using `clang` :P